# Query String Parameters are getting disappeared after page is completely loaded

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, url, query-string

I am opening a browser using URL and I am manually putting my query parameters along with the url of the webpage.
As soon as my page is loaded completely my query string parameters are getting disappeared and are replaced by **LANG=EN-US#**

I am opening as below,

```
http://mywebip/test.aspx?lang=en-us&userid={4BA50DE4-7CF7-E811-9677-00155D4B5214}
```

After load is completed the url becomes,

```
http://mywebip/test.aspx?lang=en-us#
```

Why does it disappears after my page load is completed? I have even tried on a fresh browser with no History or cookie or cache but still the issue is same.

Answer (score -1):

the reasons the above link isn’t validating is because they contain non-encoded ampersand ( & ) characters. Ampersands are often used in URL query strings to demarcate granular chunks of information"

try this
http://mywebip/test.aspx?lang=en-us&userid={4BA50DE4-7CF7-E811-9677-00155D4B5214}

visit this link it will help you.
https://perishablepress.com/how-to-write-valid-url-query-string-parameters/